# Looking for a way to adjust the values of one array based on another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I started with a set of bivariate data. My goal is to first find points in that data set for which the y-values are outliers. Then, I wanted to create a new data set that included not only the outlier points, but also any points with an x-value of within 0.01 of any given outlier point.

Then (if possible) I want to subtract the original outlier x-values from the new x-set, so that I have a group of points with x-values of between -0.01 and 0.01, with x-value now indicating distance from an original outlier x-value.

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

mean = np.mean(y)
SD = np.std(y)

x_indices = [i for i in range(len(y)) if ((y[i]) > ((2*SD)+mean))]

expanded_indices = [i for i in range(len(x)) if np.any((abs(x[i] - x[x_indices])) < 0.01)]
```

This worked great, and now I can call (and plot) x and y using the indices:

```
plt.plot(x[expanded_indices],y[expanded_indices])
```

However, I have no idea how to subtract the original "x_indices" values to get an x range of -0.01 to 0.01, since everything I tried failed.

I want to do something like what I have below, except I know that I can't subtract two arrays of different sizes, and I'm worried I can't use np.any in this context either.

```
x_values = [(x[expanded_indices] - x[indices]) if np.any((abs(x[expanded_indices] - x[indices])) < 0.01)]
```

Any ideas? I'm sorry this is so long -- I'm very new at this and pretty lost. I've been giving it a go for the last few hours and any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

sample data could be as follows:
x =[0,0.994,0.995,0.996,0.997,0.998,1.134,1.245,1.459,1.499,1.500,1.501,2.103,2.104,2.105,2.106]

y =
[1.5,1.6,1.5,1.6,10,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.6,1.6,1.5,1.6,1.5,11,1.6,1.5]

Comment: Can you add sample data for us to play around with using the given code?

Comment: Sure -- I'll try to figure out how to do that now.

Comment: Hopefully I added it in an okay format?
The real data I'm working with came in a large .npz file and I felt it would be easier for you guys if I made fake data?

Comment: you should really just start by reading a numpy tutorial my friend

Comment: that's where it's at for all python based scientific computing

Comment: it will allow you do to do what you are trying to do

Comment: @katydidit can you please put the initial declaration of _x_ and _y_? Are they lengths the same? I am not sure if I getting it right (I think that you should improve the readability of the post), are the original _x_ and _y_ elements related?

Comment: okay, thanks. i've been trying to get through tutorials but i got sidetracked by this project. is there any particular numpy function that you think could help me here? i can try to look into it.

Comment: @Jalo the lengths of x and y are necessarily the same, since they came from a bivariate set of data points. I'm sorry if I was confusing -- I didn't know how better to describe!

Comment: I know that sometimes it is difficult to explain, don't worry. As an advice, you should try to sum it up better. Try to structure first the information you want to write (in your mind or in a paper) and then write it clear. I think that you wrote some meaningless information. Anyway, may you give the values of SD and mean that you are using?

Comment: @Jalo -- updated!

Comment: @katydidit look if the answer below is what you were looking for, as I am not sure if I got your idea

Comment: The tricky bit is there can be multiple outliers within an x-distance of 0.01. So you have to decide which outlier you want to subtract. Any distance? Or the minumum distance, or max or mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the set with y-outliers values and the set with the expanded values, you can go over the whole second set with a for loop and subtract the corresponding 1st set value using 2 `For()` loops:

```
import numpy as np

x =np.array([0,0.994,0.995,0.996,0.997,0.998,1.134,1.245,1.459,1.499,1.500,1.501,2.103,2.104,2.105,2.106])
y = np.array([1.5,1.6,1.5,1.6,10,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.6,1.6,1.5,1.6,1.5,11,1.6,1.5])
mean = np.mean(y)
SD = np.std(y)
# elements with y-element outside defined region
indices = [i for i in range(len(y)) if ((y[i]) > ((2*SD)+mean))]
my_1st_set = x[indices]
# Set with values within 0.01 difference with 1st set points
expanded_indices = [i for i in range(len(x)) if np.any((abs(x[i] - x[x_indices])) < 0.01)]
my_2nd_set = x[expanded_indices]
# A final set with the subtracted values from the 2nd set
my_final_set = my_2nd_set
for i in range(my_final_set.size):
    for j in range(my_1st_set.size):
        if abs(my_final_set[i] - my_1st_set[j]) < 0.01:
            my_final_set[i] = x[i] - my_1st_set[j]
            break
```

my_final_set is a numpy array with the resulting values of subtracting the original expanded_indices values with their corresponding value of the first set

Comment: thank you for this, and for your patience!
it took me some time to adapt this to my real data set, but this works well and i really really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad that it was useful. Take into account as well the advice that a user commented on the original post about conflicts when the condition is achieved in more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood you correctly. This code should find the outliers, and put an array into res for each outlier.

```
import numpy as np

mean = np.mean(y)
SD = np.std(y)

x = np.array([0,0.994,0.995,0.996,0.997,0.998,1.134,1.245,1.459,1.499,1.500,1.501,2.103,2.104,2.105,2.106])
y = np.array([1.5,1.6,1.5,1.6,10,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.6,1.6,1.5,1.6,1.5,11,1.6,1.5])

outlier_indices = np.abs(y - mean) > 2*SD

res = []
for x_at_outlier in x[np.flatnonzero(outlier_indices)]:
    part_res = x[np.abs(x - x_at_outlier) < 0.01]
    part_res -= np.mean(part_res)
    res.append(part_res)
```

`res` is now a list of arrays, with each array containing the values around one outlier. Perhaps it is easier to continue working with the data in this format?

If you want all of them in one numpy array:

```
res = np.hstack(res)
```

Comment: wow, thanks! i didn't think of doing it this way.
i'll try adapting this to my code -- thank you so much!